# How to send a transaction with custom data to a Solana program in Python

Tags: python, solana.py

I'm new to solana development, and I've been reading docs all morning and I can't seem to find a way to send a transaction to a program with custom data. I tried using TransactionInstruction but it seems like it's deprecated or something. Does anyone have some sort of sample code to guide me in the right direction here? It'd be much appreciated.

Comment: start here https://kevinheavey.github.io/solders/tutorials/transactions.html#sending-sol